# Langtag For each webpage

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

Does the href lang tags have to be different for each page on a website or can i put the same one in the header with the main part of the site url.

is this correct or is there a different way of doing it?

Home page

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-GB" href="http://es.example.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="http://en.example.com/" />
```

Sample page

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-GB" href="http://es.example.com/page1" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="http://en.example.com/page1" />
```

Comment: `es-GB` isn't, AFAIK, a valid language code.

Answer (score 0):

The `hreflang` attribute should describe the language of the page being linked to.

A `<link>` element with `rel="alternate"` should have an `href` attribute that points to an alternative version of *the document in which the link appears* so you should not link to the Spanish homepage from the English contact page (for example).

Comment: thats why i've used a <link /> instead of <a />